# Ruby: Is Date greater than a particular date

Tags: ruby, date-comparison

I am trying to do a date comparison like so:

```
if date > "Sept 22"
#do stuff
else
#do other stuff
end
```

I just can't think of how to do this in Ruby (well at least looking at a particular date).

Answer (score 6):

Normal comparison operators work with [dates](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) too:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.new(2012,3,3)

if date > Date.new(2011,4,4)
  # do whatever
end
```

Comment: ha! man, I am so dumb... been really crazy with some projects I have been working on... I just realized how do to this lol.. thanks for your help! Credit to you for the answer :)